# Filtering a LINQ query by DateTime causing System.NotSupportedException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a database table containing a list of Secondary School Surveys. I have a controller which displays a list of the entries in the DB table. I am trying to allow a user to search for specific survey entries on "dd-MM-yyyy" date.

I have tried the following, although the return View(surveys.ToPagedList(pagerNumber, pageSize)) throws the following error when I search for a date:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.'

My Index Controller:

```
// GET: SecondarySchoolSurvey
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

            //paging
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var surveys = from s in db.SecondarySchoolSurveys
                           select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                surveys = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.Where(s => s.OfficialSchoolName.Contains(searchString) || s.RollNumber.Contains(searchString) || s.CampDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(searchString));
            }


            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    surveys = surveys.OrderByDescending(s => s.OfficialSchoolName);
                    break;
                default:
                    surveys = surveys.OrderBy(s => s.OfficialSchoolName);
                    break;
            }



            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(surveys.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

I could possibly use the SqlFunctions class i.e. SqlFunctions.StringConvert but how would I then convert DateTime to the correct format (dd-MM-yyyy)?

I also tried converting the search string to DateTime although kept getting a Sys.FormatException: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                surveys = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys.Where(s => s.OfficialSchoolName.Contains(searchString) || s.RollNumber.Contains(searchString) || s.CampDate == dt);
        }
```

Comment: Whats the reasoning behind converting a date to a string and using contains? explain this a little further

Comment: Hi @MichaelRandall, I tried converting the search string to DateTime although kept getting a Sys.FormatException: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime". Could you recommend the best practice? I have updated my post with the last method

Comment: So you have a search string, that could contain school name, or something else, or date. and if the search string is a date you want to return the records on that date?

Comment: Correct, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question you could use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

```
// Read the documentation on TryParse
var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(searchString, out var searchDate);

// the assumption is if it's a date, 
// then it's not going to satisfy any other search requirements 
if (isDate)
{
    // note, I use .Date as it's likely you don't want to compare time as well
    surveys = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys
                .Where(s => s.CampDate.Date = searchDate.Date);
} 
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    surveys = db.SecondarySchoolSurveys
                .Where(s => 
                   s.OfficialSchoolName.Contains(searchString) || 
                   s.RollNumber.Contains(searchString))
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : There are other variations of how to do this, you could have it all in a single query, though I think this is explicit and is simple to understand</sub>